# onProgressUpdate is not being called android

Tags: java, android, async-onprogressupdate

I have this `GetAllUsers();` in `onCreate` and I have this

```
private void GetAllUsers() {
  (new LoadingUsers(this)).execute();
}
```

Then I have this

```js
private class LoadingUsers extends AsyncTask < Void, Integer, String > {
  String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
  AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle;
  ArrayAdapter < String > arrayAdapter;@
  SuppressWarnings("unused")
  Context mContext;

  public LoadingUsers(Context context) {
    super();

    mContext = context;

  }

  protected void onPreExecute() {
    //            prgDialog.show();
    //            builderSingle = new
    Log.d(TAG + " PreExceute", "On pre Exceute......");
  }

  protected String doInBackground(Void...arg0) {

    Log.d(TAG + " DoINBackGround", "On doInBackground...");
    return null;
  }

  protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...a) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(a);
    Log.d(TAG + " onProgressUpdate", "You are in progress update ... " + a[0]);


  }

  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    //            prgDialog.hide();
    Log.d(TAG + " onPostExecute", "" + result);


    MainActivity.this.pd.dismiss();
  }
}
```

I wanted to put a `builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);` inside the `protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... a) {` which has a `AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();` but unfortunately the onProgressUpdate does not get called at all. I know this because the log does not show. All other `log` are showing except the `onProgressUpdate` I have also have

```
@
Override
protected void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  Log.i(TAG, "On Destroy .....");
}

@
Override
protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  Log.i(TAG, "On Pause .....");
}

@
Override
protected void onRestart() {
  super.onRestart();
  Log.i(TAG, "On Restart .....");
}

@
Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  Log.i(TAG, "On Resume .....");
}

@
Override
protected void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  Log.i(TAG, "On Start .....");
}

@
Override
protected void onStop() {
  super.onStop();
  Log.i(TAG, "On Stop .....");
}
```

`OnStart` and `OnResume` are being log as well.

Why is onProgressUpdate not being called?
How to call the onProgressUpdated correctly?

`Update`

`onPostExecute` is being called as well on the `onProgressUpdate` is not

Comment: I think you need to call publishProgress in doInBackGround()?

Comment: Where are you calling publishProgress?

Comment: @Raghavendra is it a question or an answer?because from the example i found in SO they dont call that on doInBackGround

Comment: @BrownmanRevival No you need to call publishProgress to get update on onProgressUpdate.

Comment: @BrownmanRevival use publishProgress(Progress...) to publish one or more units of progress. These values are published on the UI thread, in the onProgressUpdate(Progress...). Its an answer:)

Comment: @Raghavendra i see let me try it give me a minute

Comment: @Raghavendra i see can you post that one as answer so we can close the OP.Also can you add other information as to what other data i can send on the `publishProgress(Progress...)` currently i am sending String

Comment: @BrownmanRevival just read this doc please https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @BrownmanRevival based on your asyntask declaration in onProgressUpdate(Integer params) u need to have publishProgress(Integer). I made this comment because you said "currently i am sending String ".

Comment: @Raghavendra yes i changed it to string to match the required type sorry i didnt mention it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onProgressUpdate` is called on the main thread each time `publishProgress` is called from within `doInBackground` (on the background thread). This facility is provided for your convenience if you choose to use it. It's primarily useful if your task involves some kind of loop, in which case you can call `publishProgress` at each iteration. If your task simply invokes some other code, and all the processing happens somewhere you can't control, then the `publishProgress`/`onProgressUpdate` mechanism isn't going to be useful to you. In that case, you might decide to display an indeterminate progress bar before starting the task and then hide the indeterminate progress bar after it's completed.

Comment: actually this is what i am doing showing dialog and hiding `onPostExecute` but it is not showing at all. that is why i thought the problem was in the `onProgressUpdate`

Comment: Did the task simply end so quickly that you didn't see the dialog?

Comment: is there a way to check if the dialog box appear?i think i didnt appear because there is a long pause before the UI starts to show the activity page. activity page meaning the content of the current activity.

Comment: Make your task take longer. For testing purposes, you can do `try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch(InterruptedException x) { }`.

Answer (score 0):

***Your code may need following function:***

```
@Override                                                          
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer a) { 
    super.onProgressUpdate(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be very simple

```
private class LoadingUsers extends AsyncTask< Void, Integer, String > {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(), null, "Loading users...", false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        dialog.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Doing something in loop
        int max = 1024;
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            int percentageCompleted = i*100/max;
            publishProgress(percentageCompleted);
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Let me know if you didn't understand what is this code.

Answer (score 0):

Override the function instead of just copy past,
use keyword @Override